# Annoying substitution behaviour in Isabelle coming from lambda function application

Tags: lambda, substitution, isabelle

I come across this issue a lot: so I want to know if there is a convenient way around it.

Isabelle thinks that the terms `"(λg. a g) k"` and `"a k"` are the same. At least

```
lemma "(λg. a g) k = a k"
```

can be solved `by rule refl`. Fair enough. But then, in this (made up) example, the fact that Isabelle seems to treat `"(λg. a g) k"` as `"a k"` gets in the way of what looks like a perfectly valid substitution.

```
lemma blah:"(λg. a g) = (λg. sin g)"
  sorry

lemma "(λk. a k < ((b k)::'a :: {banach,real_normed_algebra_1, ord})) = (λk. (λg. a g) k < (λg. b g) k)"
  apply (subst blah)
```

There's no reason I'm using sine. I just needed a convenient constant, and all the sorts were added in just to make it type-check.

Comment: What is the type of `a`? If it is a constant of type `'a ⇒ 'a`, then the line with `subst` works for me. If it is a variable, then it has type `'a ⇒ 'a` in lemma `blah` and type `'b ⇒ 'a` in the lemma below and that is why using `subst` fails. You could add another type annotation to fix this: `"(λk::'a. a k < ((b k)::'a :: {banach,real_normed_algebra_1, ord})) = (λk. (λg. a g) k < (λg. b g) k)"`

Answer (score 4):

Now I could try it in Isabelle: Set eta_contract to false avoids the contraction

```
lemma blah:"(λg. a g) = (λg. sin g)"
  supply [[eta_contract= false]]
  sorry
```

yields

```
1. (λg. a g) = (λg. sin g)
```

I don't believe there is a good reason to activate it by default, but if you really want, you can do it with:

```
declare [[eta_contract= false]]
```

Comment: This is helpful. I usually run into the issue when looking for a proof/determining the lemma (quite often I have some function and set it equal to an arbitrary variable on the RHS, and work out what that RHS should be by using substitution). So the ability to control it is useful in that case.

Comment: Actually, I tried it out, and it doesn't give quite what I expected: I tried both declare[[eta_contract=false]] and supply [[eta_contract= false]]. lemma "a g = (λk. a k) g" still gives proof-state a g = a g...

Comment: @IIM It has an effect on the goal during the proof (the goal of blah is `(λg. a g) = (λg. sin g)`)  but not on the resulting theorems. You would break a lot of the internal machinery, if you could activate it also on theorems. For your use case, I usually name the constant `AAA` and work out the value without ever using lambdas...